# Is it possible to have a URL only be accessible through a portal?

Tags: url, port, portal

I've got a website that requires a login, this website shows a "portal" which makes it possible to go to deluge/plex/sonarr (webapps). these apps are connected to ports. so example.com:83031 = plex and example.com:83032 is sonarr (as an example).

Now if I go to example.com it prompts me a login and I if I then click on "plex", the portal goes to example.com:83031. this is correct. however, is there a way to disable a direct link to example.com:83031 (so is there a way to ONLY make it able to enter that site through portal?)

Long story short: I want example.com:83031 to ONLY be available through the portal, not if you enter it directly into the browser. is this possible?

[Editted the domains, got the point!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using reverse-proxy on Apache has fixed this issue.

[Picture describing the outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H188r.png)

Answer (score 1):

In theory, a browser *should* send a "redirect"  indicating from where you came. Hence, `example.com:83031` could check if you came from `example.com:80`. This is however not reliable.

However, if you redirect to `example.com:83031/loginOK?<GUID>` then you have explicitly encoded the redirection information, in a way that no browser can strip.

BTW, don't invent non-existent domains. `example.com` exists for a reason.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that people can still access "plex" by simply ticking "example.com:83031" in the browser? (The idea is that people can only get to plex through the portal, for safety reasons). If not, then I don't get it what you mean (my first project regarding ports and making localhost accessable on the internet).

Comment: @ChrisvanderGeld: Obviously, you'd redirect `example.com:83031/` back to `example.com:80`, and if somebody fakes a GUID you return a `403 Forbidden`. That said, professional security starts with a threat model. What attacks are you considering? MITM, brute-force, ... ? Perhaps even more important, who would attack you?

Comment: I have fixed it using a reverse-proxy on the apache server!